# Laravel - validate user input for unique value

Tags: mysql, laravel, validation

I have a form for managing services where **service-url** is a unique value. When i add a new service with a service_url that already exists in the database it returns  `SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry`.

What i want to do is modify my code to return back to the view with **service url already exists!**. How do i do that?

**Store service function:**

```
 public function store(Request $request)
{
    $request->validate([
        'service_url'=>'required',
        'client'=>'required',
        'service'=>'required',
        'domain_provider'=>'required',
        'domain_expiry'=>'required',
        'hosting_provider'=> 'required',
        'hosting_expiry' => 'required'
    ]);


    $share = new Service([
        'service_url' => $request->get('service_url'),
        'client' => $request->get('client'),
        'service' => $request->get('service'),
        'domain_provider' => $request->get('domain_provider'),
        'domain_expiry' => $request->get('domain_expiry'),
        'hosting_provider' => $request->get('hosting_provider'),
        'hosting_expiry' => $request->get('hosting_expiry')
    ]);
    $share->save();
    return redirect('/shares')->with('success', 'Service has been added');
}
```

I'm new to Laravel, your help would be appreciated :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add following rule in your validation, it will check `services` table for uniqueness of `service_url` column.

```
'service_url'=>'required|unique:services',
```

I hope you understand.

You can see laravel offical docs https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/validation#rule-unique

Comment: Solves the issue. Thank you.

Comment: @MaramAlSaegh Great ! !